# Why does this magnetic charger cause short circuit when it sticks to the metal leg of my table?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electronics, electrical-engineering, short-circuits

Recently, I have bought [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Magnetic-Charging-Multiple-Micro-Light-Type-Data-Fast/dp/B07HRSFRLM) product. It is basically a USB cable, with a magnetic end, and a tiny attachment that goes into the mobile device.

I plugged it into my laptop cooling stand (which has USB hub), and then plugged the tiny "adapter" into my phone. The magnetic end of the cable was free, and it stuck onto the metal leg of my work table.

It caused short circuit and burnt the fan. I only realized this after I plugged it into my laptop, and the same thing caused the laptop to restart immediately.

What is the reason behind this? The leg of my table is not connected to my computer, obviously. So, how come this USB cable was able to burn my fan, and restart my laptop?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Is your table's metallic leg connected to ground? Maybe you experienced an enormous discharge from power source to the infinite electron sink that ground is. I agree, you might find better answers either on Electrical or Engineering SE

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks! I will ask the question there.

Comment: @Steeven It is not grounded. There is a plastic between the leg and the wooden floor.

Comment: @padawan if you just hold on a moment, the mods may migrate the question - so don't ask it there straight away :)